# How to remove a vertical bar "|" from HTML using replace()

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been having problems with this for a while now:

```
v = jQuery("span.count").html().replace(/\(|\)/g, "");
jQuery("span.count").html(v);
```

I found this on SO which work great for brackets but I can't seem to get it to work with the vertical bar `|`.

Comment: You will have to escape the | character, because it is a regex operator.

Comment: FYI, this problem has nothing to do with jQuery. Regular expressions and string processing are part of the JavaScript language itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`|` is a character that is used in regex as "or". What your regex says is "replace anything that is *(nothing)* or *(nothing)* with an empty string". Escape the `|` using a backslash as such:

```
string.replace(/\|/g, "");
//              ^ Escape it!
```